# React: Require image using variable as url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm currently making a React application where you can find drink recipes. All the drink recipes are located in a MongoDB. When I GET a drink from the database I want to display the recipe with an image but I'm unable to require it by doing the following.

```
<img src={require(`../images/${drink.filename}`)} alt=""/>

Error: Cannot find module './'
```

I don't know if this is even possible or if I have to do it another way but thanks in advance :)

Comment: This should helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014790/7832687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `create-react-app` you can access files in `public` directory using path

change it to

```
<img src={`images/${drink.filename}`} alt=""/>
```