# How to Serve Media Files in Django + React

Tags: reactjs, django, image

I'm confused about serving media files on django and react. Here is my code:

Here is my settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-user/', include('landingpage.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Render it on react :

```
<img
  src="/img/logo.jpeg"  // is it true?
/>
```

I put my image on build/img folder. When i open with localhost 3000 it's rendered but when i open with localhost 8000, i get not found error with this image link http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/logo.jpeg

My question is :

Where to put images? Should i create media folder to store all my image or put it on build/image folder? How to specify the src link to image on in react?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your original config Django looking the files in media dir, not in build/img dir

> Change media files settings from
>
> ```
> MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
> ```
>
> To
>
> If you are storing images inside the `build/img` folder as you
> mentioned in the comments  then `MEDIA_URL` &  `MEDIA_ROOT` should be
> like
>
> ```
> MEDIA_URL = "/img/" #edited
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/img') #if the build dir is in root directory, if not then change it accordingly
> ```

Now you can use the access image files in This URL Pattern   http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/logo.jpeg

Comment: Can you please add the Image model in the question details?

Comment: i dont have image model, i just want to display image from local (inside build/img folder)

Comment: @penk Please check the edited Answer now.

Comment: it still get 404 error in localhost8000. should i let django handle the media file (put the image inside media folder) or let react handle it? (put the image inside build folder)

Answer (score 0):

Answering:

- Put react images into `public/static` react project directory, so they will be moved to `build/static` and later served as other static files
- In react there is something called `PUBLIC_LINK`. I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014790/14126078) answer

I can propose more general approach for react+django in production:

- In `settings.py` create 3 varibles:

  - `REACT_DIR` – for your react project root
  - `REACT_ROOT_URL_FILES` – list of filenames to be served via root url *(e.g. /favicon.png)*
  - `STATICFILES_DIRS` – add directory where react created static files bundles

```
#settings.py

REACT_DIR = os.environ.get('REACT_DIR','/path/to/react/app/')
REACT_ROOT_URL_FILES = os.environ.get("REACT_ROOT_URL_FILES",'favicon.png manifest.json robots.txt').split(" ")

STATIC_URL = f'/{os.environ.get("STATIC_URL","static")}/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    #...
    os.path.join(REACT_DIR,'build','static')
]
```

- Then in `views.py` write view to handle react root dir files (of names from `REACT_ROOT_URL_FILES`) as also react `index.html`:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse,FileResponse
from django.conf import settings
import os


class ServeReactView(View):

    def get(self,request):
        try:
            url  = request.path.strip('/')
            if url in settings.REACT_ROOT_URL_FILES:
                #return one of the files named from the list
                file_name = url
                file = open(os.path.join(settings.REACT_DIR,'build',file_name),'rb')
                return FileResponse(file)

            with open(os.path.join(settings.REACT_DIR,'build','index.html')) as file:
                #return react index.html
                return HttpResponse(file.read())
        except:
            return HttpResponse(
            """
            {} not found!
            """.format(request.path),status=501)
```

- And at the and add this view to `urls.py`:

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    #...
    re_path(r"^.*",ServeReactView.as_view(),name="serve_web_client_view")
]
```

**P.S**
When you're serving more common react files (images etc..) I think it's better to put them  into `public/static/` react project directory, so they will be moved to `build/static` and later served as other static files