# How do I display folders under public_html in a browser in a deployed react app?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, rest, server

For a simple html-css webpage I could access a folder of music files under the public_html and display those music files in a browser. But now I have used a React App with create-react-app. How do I access a folder I have put on a server under public_html like so  `public_html/songs/`? Current behavior when I try to hit an endpoint like
`mysite.com/songs` in a browser, it just displays React App home page regardless of the URL address, which in essence is `mysite.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to serve Static files with create-react-app from public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014651/is-it-possible-to-serve-static-files-with-create-react-app-from-public-folder)

Comment: @AndyRay op is probably asking how to route react application using some kind of server that isn't mentioned. I guess that the server is apache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup apache server for React route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038456/how-to-setup-apache-server-for-react-route)

Comment: No there is a music folder uploaded to my server in the following directory `www.mysite.com/songs/`. In a simple HTML website, I could have song files displayed in the song folder in the form of underlined links of song names.mp3 displayed in the browser but the react app that I currently have just displays a home page for react app which won't allow me hitting the songs folder to display its contents in the browser

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya, there's likely a server setting that prevents seeing the folder structure of your hosted website, so you can't just point the user to a directory and expect them to see the contents of it. You either need to change that setting (which is likely an admin setting and not changeable on purchased shared hosting) or set up a page to get a list of the contents in the folder and then dynamically create a page with links to each of those items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that my .htaccess file was configured to redirect all requests for files that are perceived to not exist to index.html: 
I was initially like so:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Now I changed it to this:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Serve existing files directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Redirect all other requests to index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```